# Keep window.open() from opening in full screen

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have the following code in a vb.net program:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('./folder/frame.aspx?x=" & x & "','_blank','height=300,width=400,location=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=yes,directories=no,copyhistory=no,resizable=yes');self.close();</script>")
```

I would expect that to open with a window that is 300x400, but it is opening full screen.

I tried it without the height and width and it also opens full screen.

I tried this:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('./folder/frame.aspx?x=" & x & "','_blank','');self.close();</script>")
```

It opens a new tab in the same browser.

How do I keep this window from opening full screen?

Answer (score 1):

I kept digging around and found this some javascript:

```
window.moveTo(0,0)
window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
```

I commented out that code and the specified height and width started to work.